# WordPress: get current child taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

i have a custom taxonomy named sm-category

Area
 - area 1
 - area 2

Shop
 - shop 1
 - shop 2

In single custom post page i want to display just the current area of the post, lets say 'area 1'.

The `get_term_children($term_id, 'sm-category')` will retrieve a list with all children but i want only the current child of the post.

Any solution there?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Than get the first child,..

```
 $subcategorys = get_term_children($term_id, 'sm-category');
 print_r($subcategorys[0]); // The first entry
```

Comment: Ah thanks! And what if i want to get the current area for each post in the archive page?

Comment: i mean in custom posts archive page. The get_the_category is only for normal posts right? not for custom posts. Am i wrong?

Comment: Its the same. Post id's are **unique**. Otherwise if you use custom taxonomys, use `$categories = get_the_terms( $id, 'TERM NAME' );`